# What could prevent Eclipse from loading an Android Library?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libraries, android-appcompat

I am currently working on an Android project, which references some **Android libraries**.

After **importing the libraries as projects** in my Workspace, I add them to my project:

`Project > Properties > Android > Library > Add...`, and I add the needed Libraries. Everything seems ok, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph06J.png).

However, as soon as I click on the `OK` button, The `appcompat` library doesn't seem to be recognized anymore (Build errors still displayed on appcompat's classes, resources missing, etc).

Indeed, the `Project > Properties > Android > Library` Menu now displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3wGu.png), showing an error **only** on the `appcompat` library.

- Am I missing/not understanding something that may explain this behaviour?
- Moreover, how can I fix this problem?

---

**[UPDATE]** Using `Project > Clean`, followed by `File > Restart`, solved the problem.

As I can now close the Android window and reopen it without the library integration failing as before, the problem seems to be definitively solved.

However, I am still clueless: what could have been the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had once one big problem related to partitions in my PC. Please, be sure that you have your source code and your libraries in the same partition. It's very important, and I hadn't read before I had the problem.

Comment: I will be aware of this now. However, all the libraries are in the same partition, being in the same root folder as shown in the `Reference` column [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph06J.png), and so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

- Copy appCompat library in the same folder where FacebookSDk and
  GooglePlayService is there.
- Import the appCompat project into your eclipse.
- Add as library to you're project. You're problem will solve.